# How to change ratings in Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, rating

I used to rate songs in Windows Media Player simply clicking the stars near each song. Quick and easy.

For some reason, this does not work anymore in WMP on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 (RTM from MSDN). When I click on the starts, the new rating is not saved. I also tried right-clicking on the song -> Rate -> N stars, no change.

Changing the rating from Windows Explorer works. Also, disabling the "Maintain my stars ratings as global ratings in files" option has no effect.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I somehow managed to get ratings working again by deleting all *.wmdb* files found in:

```
C:\Users\<USER NAME>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player
```

After deleting the files I had to rebuild the library, but ratings started working again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same 'problem', so I played a bit with WMP and found the solution. Here it is:

If you want to be able to rate music files:

```
1. Switch to Library View
2. Right-click on Music(under Library and Playlists in the leftmost panel)
3. Choose Manage Music Library
4. Add the folder where you music files are
5. Restart and you are ready to rate!
```

Basically, it's the same procedure for videos, pictures and etc.(just right click on Videos/Pictures/Whatever expandable menu in the leftmost panel)

PS: you can right-click and customize the navigation pane to add Folder view(most convenient for me), Ratings view and many more.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this exact problem! This is the solution:

Switch view to "Library"

[image]

Right click on Library and choose File -- Manage libraries -- Music

[image]

Click on "Add" and choose a folder with all your music.

[image]

After restart you will be able to change the ratings!